# Python Selenium - find item in a list

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, linktext

I have the following:

```
<a href="/firewall_aliases.php" class="navlnk">Aliases</a>
<a href="/firewall_aliases.php" class="navlnk">NAT</a>
<a href="/firewall_aliases.php" class="navlnk">Rules</a>
```

I can't seem to be able to locate the element with text *Aliases*. Is it possible to do?

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like:

`//*[text()="Aliases"]`

another way is

```
//a[@href="/firewall_aliases.php" and (text()="Aliases")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XPath locator:

```
//a[text()="Aliases"]
```

For more uniqueness you can use

```
//a[@href="/firewall_aliases.php" and (text()="Aliases")]
```

Or even

```
//a[@href="/firewall_aliases.php" and (@class="navlnk") and (text()="Aliases")]
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element with text as *`Aliases`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `link_text`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Aliases")
  ```
- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.navlnk[href*='firewall_aliases']")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Aliases' and contains(@href, 'firewall_aliases')]")
  ```

Ideally, to locate the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Aliases")))
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.navlnk[href*='firewall_aliases']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Aliases' and contains(@href, 'firewall_aliases')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```